# MySQL: Запрос в хранимой процедуре возвращает один и тот же результат

Tags: mysql, select, update, курсор, procedure

Всем привет.

Есть следующая процедура:

```
BEGIN 
Declare uid VARCHAR(300);
Declare influence integer;
Declare currentPlace integer default 0;
/* переменная hadler */
Declare done integer default 0;
/*Объявление курсора*/
Declare myCursor Cursor for SELECT `rating`.`id`,`rating_weekly`.`influence` FROM `rating` INNER JOIN `rating_weekly` ON `rating`.`id`=`rating_weekly`.`id`; 
/*HANDLER*/
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
/* открытие курсора */
Open myCursor;
/*извлекаем данные */
WHILE done = 0 DO 
  FETCH myCursor INTO uid,influence;
  SELECT count(*) FROM `rating_weekly` WHERE `influence` >= influence INTO currentPlace; 
  UPDATE `rating` SET `bestWeeklyTop`=currentPlace WHERE `id`=uid;
END WHILE;
/*закрытие курсора */
Close myCursor; 
END
```

Суть в том, что запрос

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `rating_weekly` WHERE `influence` >= influence
```

постоянно возвращает одно и тоже значение и записывает его в переменную `currentPlace`. Выборка напрямую зависит от условия **`influence` >= influence**, где переменная `influence` постоянно обновляется, но почему то это игнорируется и переменная `currentPlace` всегда содержит общее количество строк таблицы. Делая этот запрос вне процедуры, результат корректный.

Также, я проверил значения всех переменных внутри цикла - они обновляются.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Может у меня присутствуют какие-то явные ошибки в скрипте?

p.s. процедуру пишу первый раз

Comment: Я не представляю почему так происходит. Но я так же не могу понять зачем вообще какие то переменные и курсоры. Ведь то же самое можно сделать одним запросом: `UPDATE rating R 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A.id, count(*) as currentPlace
      FROM rating_weekly A, rating_weekly B
     WHERE B.influence >= A.influence
     GROUP BY A.id
   ) C
  ON R.id=C.id
 SET R.bestWeeklyTop=C.currentPlace` 
 На 100% поручится за корректность не могу, вашей базы для проверки у меня нет. но думаю что очень близок к правильному

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответ! Дело в том, что мне необходимо использовать условие IF, при котором собственно и выполняю апдейт. Для поиска ошибки скрипт упростил вырезав проверку условия.

Comment: Проверки неких условий так же можно уложить в один запрос :)

Comment: @Mike хм, окей. Почитаю в этом направлении. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вам стоит переименовать переменную `Declare influence integer;`. Никогда не называйте переменные так же как поля таблиц.

В Вашем запросе `SELECT count(*) FROM rating_weekly WHERE influence >= influence INTO currentPlace;` оба `influence` - это имя колонки таблицы и вы никак не можете подсказать компилятору, что одна из них на самом деле переменная ! В итоге ваш запрос выглядит примерно как `select count(*) ... where 5>=5`.

Comment: Это действительно так, дело в названии переменной.
Большое спасибо!